# Angular 11,Route Parameters not working in my case

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have been facing the issue on angular parameters since path routing I am able to navigate but when it's coming to parameters calling I am unable to fetch the id

Issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Oxw.png)

How to overcome this issue please help me on this

```
app-routing
----------
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:"", redirectTo:"home", pathMatch:"full"},
  {path:"home",component:HomeComponent},
  {path:"product",component:ProductComponent},`enter code here`
  {path:"prod-details/:id",component:ProductDetailsComponent},  
];
```

when I try to declare the variable it through the error

```
product-details.ts
--------------------
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private rout:ActivatedRoute) { }
  product_id="";

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  this.product_id = this.rout.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    
  }

}
```

Comment: what type of error you are getting ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda The error is in the linked image.  Looks like a type conversion `Type null is not assignable to type string`.  I'd put a debugger in the code to see what is going on in that `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: instead of this `product_id="";` add this `product_id: string | null="";` at declaration.

Comment: Got resolved the issue thank you @gaurang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      if (params.get('id')) {
        this.paramId = params.get('id');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this way, I hope it works:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {

   this.rout.params
   .subscribe( ({id}) => {
      this.product_id = id;
   })   
    
}
```